# How to fix this GeneXus environment error?

Tags: environment, development-environment, genexus

I have used GeneXus for a while but recently I got this error when trying to create a new Knowledge Base, I have tried to reinstall but still got the same error. Is there anyway to fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXbY.png)

Comment: Check whether the file `C:\Models\JBCC_GX_KIT_DEV\GX_KB_JBCC_GX_KIT_DEV.mdf` exists in your file system. If it does not exist maybe you moved that file somewhere else, then revert that move (and also .LDF file).

Comment: Reinstalling GeneXus won't fix this problem as it seems it cannot access your knowledge base files

Comment: The SQL instance you're using to create the KB may not have the correct access permissions in order to create the KB's DB in that folder. [This article](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7710,Creating%20KBs%20under%20Windows%20Vista%20or%20Windows%207) is quite old, but it still applies to newer Windows versions